# VB6 Assigning data to variables from a database

Tags: ms-access, vb6, recordset

I've been asked to make a change to a VB6 project. The issue I'm having is that I'm trying to get some data from an Access database and assign the data to some variables.

I've got the code:

```
Dta_Period.DatabaseName = DB_Accounts_Name$
Dta_Period.RecordSet = "SELECT * FROM [Period]"
Dta_Period.Refresh
```

The table `Period` contains 2 fields. `sMonth` and `Period`
The `sMonth` field contains the months January - December. The `Period` field stores a number 0 to 11, to represent what number has been assigned to which month in the customers financial year. January may be 0, or may be 11, essentially.

I need to know which month goes with which period, which is why I have selected this data from the database. However, I'm stuck with what to do next.

How can I loop over the `RecordSet` (If this is even possible?) and find out what number has been assigned to each month?

I don't think there is a way I can use a `Do Until` loop. Is it easier to just use 12 separate queries, and then create an array of strings and an array of integers and then loop over the array of strings until I find the correct month, the use the same index for the array on integers?

*EDIT 1*

To make things simpler to follow for both myself and anyone attempting to provide an answer, I have modified the code.

```
Dim rstPeriod As DAO.RecordSet
Dim accDB As DAO.Database

' DB_Session is a Workspace, whilst DB_Accounts_Name$ is the name of the DB I am using
Set accDB = DB_Session.OpenDatabase(DB_Accounts_Name$)

SQL = "SELECT * FROM [Period] ORDER BY [Period]"

Set rstPeriod = accDB.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenDynaset)

If rstPeriod.BOF = False Then
   rstPeriod.MoveFirst
End If

Dim strMonth(11) As String
Dim pNumber(11) As Integer
```

Pseudocode idea:

```
Do Until rstPeriod.EOF
   Select Case currentRow.Field("Month")
     Case "January"
       strMonth(0) = "January"
       pNumber(0) = currentRow.Field("Number")
     Case "February"
       strMonth(1) = "February"
       pNumber(1) = currentRow.Field("Number")
    End Select
Loop
```

Comment: That's some weird code you got there. You're setting a recordset equal to a string? Normally, you can just `Do Until Recordset.EOF` to loop through a recordset, but I doubt that's a normal DAO or ADO recordset you've got there. If you want a specific answer, you will have to share enough code for us to understand what's going on.

Comment: I think you should be able to do something like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243789(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Is there a recordset wrapper class by any chance?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth It's a recordset that has been referenced in another class in the same way. In the other class if I try to "Go to Definition" I get a "Cannot jump to Dta_Period because it is hidden" message.

Comment: @KostasK. My above comment may also answer your question. Never seen this source code before in my life, it's incredibly old, but the dev who usually looks after is on holiday so I've been asked to do this in his absence.

Comment: @Harambe well, then you'll have to get access to the source code of that class first (or get access to the actual recordset, and not a wrapper class).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I've re-written the code to make it easier to follow - Does that help in offering an answer at all?

Comment: @Harambe yes, now you can just use Jeremy's suggestion. Try to implement that, you can mention me if you have trouble doing so.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I think I'm almost there. One last thing, and I have added a pseudocode example onto the question to make it clearer what I mean - How can I read a field in the current row when iterating the rows of the record set?

Comment: That's just `rstPeriod.Fields("Month")`. Also, never forget `rstPeriod.MoveNext`, else you've got an infinite loop there.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth That goes between `End Select` and `Loop`, right? Then I need to close the recordset after the loop has finished.

Comment: Indeed, it does. Just like in the example Jeremy referred you to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through recordset and fill the arrays with the month name and month number.

This assumes the recordset returns no more than 12 records.

```
Public Sub LoopThroughtRecordset()
    On Error GoTo ErrorTrap

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Period] ORDER BY [Period]", dbOpenSnapShot)
    With rs
        If .EOF Then GoTo Leave
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
    End With

    Dim strMonth(11) As String
    Dim pNumber(11) As Integer

    Dim idx As Long
    For idx = 0 To rs.RecordCount -1
        strMonth(idx) = rs![Month]
        pNumber(idx) = rs![Number]
        rs.MoveNext
    Next idx

Leave:
    On Error Resume Next
        rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrorTrap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, CurrentDb.Properties("AppTitle")
    Resume Leave
End Sub

'strMonth(0) = January
'strMonth(1) = February
'...
'pNumber(0) = 1
'pNumber(1) = 2
'...
```